# converting dataframe column from object to date not datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python version 3.7.

I have a dataframe, df that contains one column called TDate.

The column looks like below.

```
 2019-01-01 00:00:00
 2019-01-02 00:00:00
 2019-01-03 00:00:00
 2019-01-04 00:00:00
```

When I do df.dtypes it tell me the column is of type object.

I then have the line below,

> myDates = pd.to_datetime(df['TDate'])

So myDates is a pandas Series.

However if I access one element of this myDates series and check the type it tells me it is a libs.tslib.timestamps.Timestamp

I just want to convert the original dataframe column from an object to a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd. What is the best way of doing this?

I looked at converting a timestamp to a date but that didn't work as the timestamp is a string literal not a integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove time information from column (or better it is set to default `00:00:00` value in each datetime):

```
myDates = pd.to_datetime(df['TDate']).dt.floor('d')
#for save to same column
#df['TDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TDate']).dt.floor('d')
```

Or [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
myDates = pd.to_datetime(df['TDate']).dt.normalize()
#for save to same column
#df['TDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TDate']).dt.normalize()
```

If use:

```
myDates = pd.to_datetime(df['TDate']).dt.date
```

then output is python dates objects, so most datetimelike functions failed.

Comment: `I just want to convert the original dataframe column from an object to a date ` mentions in the question ,why didn't you save in df['TDate']?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will convert a timestamp to date

```
df['TDate']= pd.to_datetime(df['TDate']).dt.date
```